# Create Unix shell script to move non empty files from Source directory to Target directory and add timestamp to them

Tags: linux, unix, cygwin

I am trying to Create a shell script to move non empty files from Source directory to Target directory and add timestamp to them.
I am using

```
find . -type f -size +0 -print0 | xargs -I {} -r0 mv {} $Tgt_dir/{}_`date +%m%d%Y`
```

but its not working. Could you please help.

Thanks

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: What is it doing wrong?

Comment: `{}` will contain the full pathname. So it will try to write `dir1/dir2/filename` to `$Tgt_dir/dir1/dir2/filename_<date>`. If the subdirectories don't exist in the target, `mv` won't create them automatically.

Comment: That's right. Its trying to move non zero size to Tgt_dir/Src_dir/filename. How would we move it to only Tgt_dir. Thanks!

Comment: You should edit the question to explain the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-printf` in `find` to print the `mv` command with the full path of the source and just the basename in the destination, and pipe that to the shell:

```
date=$(date +%m%d%Y)
find . -type f -size +0 -printf "mv '%p' '$Tgt_dir/%f_$date'" | bash
```

`%p` is the full pathname, `%f` is the basename.

To move files with at least one line, write a command that counts the number of lines:

```
date=$(date +%m%d%Y)
find "$Src_dir" -type f -size +0 -printf "if [ $(wc -l '$p') -gt 1 ]; then mv '%p' '$Tgt_dir/%f_$date'; fi" | bash
```

Comment: This worked. I replaced "find ." with "find $Src_dir". Thank you!

Comment: How would I do the same thing, but this time move files with more than 1 line in them. Thanks

Comment: find $Src_dir -type f| xargs wc -l| sed 's/^ *//g'|grep -v '^1 '|egrep -v ' total' | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev | xargs -I {}  mv $Src_dir/{} $Tgt_dir/{}`date +%m%d%Y`

Comment: Is that supposed to be a question?